# MATLAB Video: how to use 'readFrame' output for 'imbinarize' function?

Tags: matlab, video

I'm doing the following:1. Loading the original video 2. converting the video to black and white 3. saving it to a new avi file. 
 Repeating for each frame.

;

However I got the the following error:

Expected I to be two-dimensional

Why am I getting this error message? Isn't a frame going to be two-dimensional?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The image from your video is an RGB image so it is `M x N x 3` and `imbinarize` only accepts 2D inputs. In order to process your image, you'll want to first convert it from RGB to grayscale using `rgb2gray`

```
img = rgb2gray(readFrame(reader));
```

Also, since the output of `imbinarize` is `logical`, you'll need to first convert it to a `double` prior to writing it to the output video

```
writeVideo(writer, double(BW));
```

Comment: @tami You can do it either before or after, it shouldn't matter. I would assume that `graythresh` calls `rgb2gray` internally for RGB inputs anyhow

Comment: thank you! I still have an Error: "Error Using writeVideo, IMG must be of one of the following classes: double, single, unit8" Why?

Comment: Thanks again!! May I ask: if I wish to turn the whole code to a function with no output and an input which is a path to the original video, will it be enough just to add at the top of the code: function[]= MyFunc(args)?

Comment: @tami Yes and use `args` as the name of your video. Also you don't need the explicit `[]` you can just do `function MyFunc(args)`